# How to prove a bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

[image]

I know what a bijection is and how to prove it when given a function, but how to do it when you are only given sets.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the cardinality of each set is $4$. So we are assured a bijection exists. Why?

To create an explicit bijection, 
you must assign to each element in the first set, exactly one element in the second set ensuring that *no two elements* in the first set are assigned to the same element in the second set. Because the sets each have $4$ elements, doing this will assure that no element in the second set is "left out".

One very natural way to to this is as follows: Index the elements in each set $1\leq i \leq 4$ from left to right, and assign the $i$th element of the first set to the $i$th element in the second set.

Comment: Okay, thats what I was thinking, but just wanted to clarify!